# How to extract two numbers from an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

Below is the string I have

```
NSString *myString = @"file_1_23.pdf";
                            ^ ^^
```

What I want to extract is 1 & 23.

Any idea how to get this?

Other possible of string can be

```
NSString *myString = @"file_12_2.pdf";
NSString *myString = @"file_123_8.pdf";
```

---

I believe I need to use method `- (NSString *)substringWithRange:(NSRange)range;`, but confused on how to get second index of _

Format for string is

```
file_anyNumber_anyNumber.fileExtension
```

NOTE: It have `_` two times and this is making me crazy.

Comment: Could you tell me is your string starts with `file_` all the time?

Comment: @prasaddevadiga : yes... format is same... number can be various and end can be pdf or docx or png..

Comment: downvoters : What is problem in question? _ is two times... which is making me difficult...

Comment: @FahimParker if the string is `@"file_123__8.pdf` you want the string to be `123  8` with 2 spaces, am I correct ?

Comment: The problem with your question is that it exactly matches the string describing the down-arrow when hovering above it.

Comment: @prasaddevadiga : no... two different strings... please...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will break the components of your string into an array of strings.

```
NSString *myString = @"file_123_8.pdf";

NSCharacterSet *delimiters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"_."];
NSArray *components = [myString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:delimiters];
```

Now the `components` array contains string-objects `@"file", @"123", @"8", @"pdf"`

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *myString = @"file_123_8.pdf";

NSArray *subStrings = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];

NSString *myFirstString = [subStrings objectAtIndex:1];

NSString *lastString = [subStrings objectAtIndex:2];

NSArray *subStrings = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

NSString *mySecondString = [subStrings objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"First String is : %@  ,Second String is : %@", myFirstString, mySecondString);
```

OUTPUT will be

```
First String is : 123  ,Second String is : 8
```

Comment: +1 : It is working. but I think, Jeff Wolski answer is best.. :)

Comment: @FahimParkar, yes thats right. thanx anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help You.

```
-(NSString*)stringBetweenString:(NSString*)start andString:(NSString)end {
    NSRange startRange = [self rangeOfString:start];
    if (startRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSRange targetRange;
        targetRange.location = startRange.location + startRange.length;
        targetRange.length = [self length] - targetRange.location;   
        NSRange endRange = [self rangeOfString:end options:0 range:targetRange];
        if (endRange.location != NSNotFound) {
           targetRange.length = endRange.location - targetRange.location;
           return [self substringWithRange:targetRange];
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: can you provide with above string example? Note it have _ two times...

Answer (score 0):

Add category to NSString (NSString+Regex)

There implement method

```
- (NSArray *)matches:(NSString *)pattern
{
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:nil];

    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:self options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, self.length)];

    matches;
}
```

Now in your whatever method do

```
NSArray *matches = [myString matches:@"(\\d)"];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) 
{
    NSString *singleMatch = [myString match.range];
    NSLog(@"%@",singleMath);
}
```

This is untested but should work. If you don't want to make a category, simple add that method somewhere else, add a string as one of the parameters and replace `self` by that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of good answers here.

For completeness, a solution based on NSScanner, a class explicitly made for this sort of task (not that the other solutions aren't valid, of course).

```
NSString *myString = @"file_1_23.pdf";
NSString *firstString;
NSString *secondString;

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: myString];

NSCharacterSet *digits = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];

[scanner scanUpToString: @"_" intoString: NULL];
[scanner scanString: @"_" intoString: NULL];      // Consume the underscore

// Now, read the the first number
[scanner scanUpToString: @"_" intoString: &firstString];

[scanner scanString: @"_" intoString: NULL];      // Consume this underscore, too

// Read the second number
[scanner scanUpToString: @"." intoString: &secondString];
```

There are other ways to scan through the string but this one explicitly scans past the two underscore characters (`_`) that you mention.